# Rotating animation image gallery iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to do an animation that makes images rotate something like this

[image]

Anyone got idea or any api through which this is possible? Or any hints/startups

Comment: Just a quick note. This isn't a coverflow animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take look at the carousel library :[iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). In this you can do above animations using **iCarouselTypeWheel** . This is simple to implement and easy to understand.

Comment: Nice, not heard of this before.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UICollectionView` for this with a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`.

There are a number of WWDC talks from both 2012 and 2013 that cover layouts like this in `UICollectionView` that you could look at.